# Аутентификация через ВКонтакте (какой пароль делать)

Tags: vkontakte-api, api

Делаю регистрацию/вход через ВКонтакте, через api получаю айди, имя, фамилию и т.д. всё будет работать через одну кнопку, то есть если в бд нет пользователя с таким айди то регистрируем его, если есть, то входим на сайт.

Вопрос таков, при регистрации какой генерировать пароль? В мыслях перевести имя/фамилию на латиницу добавить пару символов для безопасности и зашифровать её в md5. Не сталкивался с этим, вот и спрашиваю как правильно сделать момент с паролем.

Так же ещё возникнет проблема если пользователь захочет поменять пароль уже на сайте, для безопасности сделал при смене пароля пользователь должен ввести старый пароль. Но как он введёт старый пароль, не зная его, можно конечно сделать если пользователь зареган с вк, то первую смену пароля, отключить ввод старого пароля.

Что скажете по этому поводу?

Answer (score 0):

А зачем создавать пароль, если подделать через авторизацию ВК id невозможно? Просто достаточно сделать такой же вход, и тогда будет проверяться только id, и нагрузка будет поменьше.

- Вместо md5 используй password_hash и PASSWORD_BCRYPT.
- Можно перевести символы в другие по созданным правилам (replace a=>Z, n=>l и так далее в другие символы) и воспользоваться функцией password_hash.

Comment: что то вообще не пойму, "А зачем создавать пароль" а как не создавать? Не оставлю я же зарегестриованную строку (пользователя) без пароля

Comment: Я же вам сказал - просто делайте и регистрацию и вход через ВКонтакте. Таким образом вы сможете обойтись только id. Пароль не нужен просто будет.